# Keep the last occurance of the field data and delete the others occuance of the same field data in csv file

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have a unsorted csv file which totally contains 6 fields. There is a duplicate in field1. Need to keep the last occurance of field1 and delete the other duplicate records for that same field1 value. I have tried **awk -F',' '!seen[$1]++'** - but this keep first occurance and deleting the other occurance.

can anyone help me with other options?

## Sample data:

```
17710813,24759,
17722388,47281,,,,
17722388,1999084,0246,car,28-Jul-11,
17722388,1159769,11301,earn,16-Jun-16,
17722388,136787,35451,dress,,15-Jun-16
17732315,242393,,light,28-Aug-05,21-Jul-08
```

## Expected output

```
17710813,24759,
17722388,136787,35451,dress,,15-Jun-16
17732315,242393,,light,28-Aug-05,21-Jul-08
```

Comment: With your shown samples please try following `awk` code: `awk -F',' '{arr[$1]=$0} END{for(i in arr){print arr[i]}}' Input_file`

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code this will take care of the sequence in which `$1` is occurring in output also.

```bash
awk -F',' '
!arr1[$1]++{
  arr2[++count]=$1
}
{
  arr3[$1]=$0
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print arr3[arr2[i]]
  }
}
' Input_file
```

***OR*** if $1's sequence as per Input_file doesn't matter for you then try following code.

```bash
awk -F',' '{arr[$1]=$0} END{for(i in arr){print arr[i]}}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have tagged your question `unix` I presume that command other that `awk` are allowed and thus you might use [`tac`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tac.1.html) as follows, let `file.txt` content be

```
17710813,24759,
17722388,47281,,,,
17722388,1999084,0246,car,28-Jul-11,
17722388,1159769,11301,earn,16-Jun-16,
17722388,136787,35451,dress,,15-Jun-16
17732315,242393,,light,28-Aug-05,21-Jul-08
```

then

```
tac file.txt | awk -F',' '!seen[$1]++' | tac
```

gives output

```
17710813,24759,
17722388,136787,35451,dress,,15-Jun-16
17732315,242393,,light,28-Aug-05,21-Jul-08
```

Explanation: `tac` does

> concatenate and print files in reverse

therefore last line of file will appear as first and so on. Akin to GNU `AWK` it will read listed file(s) as in `tac file.txt` and when not given any file then consume standard input as seen in last part of code above. `awk` part is copied verbatim from your question.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*